# Ajax - how to get data from database and put it on text area CKeditor

Tags: php, ajax, ckeditor, codeigniter-3

i have problem to get data from database to put it on my CKeditor value.
because i want to edit data. and i should show data from database

i using ajax to the data

my ajax

```
function EditNews(id_news)
    {
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        }
        //Ajax Load data from ajax
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('admin-spot/news/EditNews')?>/"+id_news,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data)
            {

                $('[name="title_news"]').val(data.title_news);
                $('[name="id_news"]').val(data.id_news);
                $('[name="text_news"]').val(data.text)
                $('[name="date"]').datepicker('update',data.join_date);


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: update what ur getting and what ur not..

Comment: So what is the code in your news controller / editnews method?

Comment: Take a look into sample where you can dynamically create and destroy editor instance.
https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full-all/samples/old/ajax.html